# VUE 2.x.x and AUTH0 - page protection blocking direct links

Tags: vuejs2, auth0

I have made a small web-app https://horselog.bjerge.com/

I have used the guide from this site to implement AUTH0:
https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/blob/main/tutorial/vue2-login.md

When i login and use the navbar link to access the page logbook it works fine, but if i go directly to https://horselog.bjerge.com/logbook i get "404 Not Fond".

I'm believe that this part here could make the issue:

```
`import { getInstance } from './index'

export const authGuard = (to, from, next) => {
  const authService = getInstance()

  const fn = () => {
    // If the user is authenticated, continue with the route
    if (authService.isAuthenticated) {
      return next()
    }

    // Otherwise, log in
    authService.loginWithRedirect({ appState: { targetUrl: to.fullPath } })
  }

  // If loading has already finished, check our auth state using `fn()`
  if (!authService.loading) {
    return fn()
  }

  // Watch for the loading property to change before we check isAuthenticated
  authService.$watch('loading', loading => {
    if (loading === false) {
      return fn()
    }
  })
}
`
```

It work find when running in v-code with npm run serve, but when i deploy to my local apache or my web-hotel i stops working.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your Apache/nginX (or whatever web server you're using) to serve `index.html` instead of 404 errors.
For nginX it looks like this (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;
}
```

For Apache2 (in `.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or you can switch your VueRouter from `history` to `hash` mode.